# XSLT - Sum based on attribute values

Tags: xslt

I have following source XML

**Source XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<PropertySet><SiebelMessage><ListOfXRX_spcUSCO_spcCOL_spcInvoice_spcAR_spcSummary>
<FS_spcInvoice 
Type_spcCode="20" 
XCS_spcINQ_spcPO_spcNumber="7500020052"  
XCS_spcINQ_spcSerial_spcNumber="VDR551061"
XCS_spcINQ_spcCustomer_spcNumber="712246305"
XCS_spcINQ_spcInvoice_spcNumber="060853967"
Gross_spcAmount="747.06"
Invoice_spcDate="04/01/2012"></FS_spcInvoice>
<FS_spcInvoice
Type_spcCode="20" 
XCS_spcINQ_spcPO_spcNumber="7500020052"  
XCS_spcINQ_spcSerial_spcNumber="VDR551061"
XCS_spcINQ_spcCustomer_spcNumber="712346305"
XCS_spcINQ_spcInvoice_spcNumber="063853967"
Gross_spcAmount="947.06"
Invoice_spcDate="04/01/2013"></FS_spcInvoice>
</ListOfXRX_spcUSCO_spcCOL_spcInvoice_spcAR_spcSummary></SiebelMessage></PropertySet>
```

I need to generate sorted list of invoices in HTML format. I am able to do that with help following XSLT

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/" >
<html><head></head><body>
<H3>Summary</H3>    
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Invoice Number</th><th>Customer Number</th><th>Serial Number</th><th>PO Number</th><th>Invoice Date</th><th>Invoice Amount</th></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<xsl:apply-templates select="PropertySet/SiebelMessage/ListOfXRX_spcUSCO_spcCOL_spcInvoice_spcAR_spcSummary/FS_spcInvoice">
<xsl:sort select="@Gross_spcAmount" order="descending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
<tr><td colspan="5">Total Amount</td><td></td></tr>
</tbody></table></body></html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='FS_spcInvoice'>
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@XCS_spcINQ_spcInvoice_spcNumber" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@XCS_spcINQ_spcCustomer_spcNumber" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@XCS_spcINQ_spcSerial_spcNumber" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@XCS_spcINQ_spcPO_spcNumber" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Invoice_spcDate" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Gross_spcAmount" /></td>
 </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have two questions

**1. How to SUM?**

I need to display sum of all invoices in the last row of the table. I have an idea that I need to use nodeset but I am not able to figure out how?

**2. Dynamic Sort**

Is it possible to provide element name or attribute name dynamically to xsl:sort.

For example the attribute name on which to sort is provided as different element value.

```
<sortby>Gross_spcAmount</sortby>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) How to sum: use the built-in XPath library.

```
sum(/PropertySet/*/FS_spcInvoice)
```

There is a nuance if there is a risk that any of the numbers being addressed are not actually numbers, in which case the sum would be spoiled by including the bad value.  This is prevented by:

```
sum(/PropertySet/*/FS_spcInvoice[number(.)=number(.)])
```

... which relies on the property of `NaN` that `NaN != NaN`.

(2) Dynamic sort:  it is possible, though inelegant ... you have to express the calculation of the sort string using an address that composes the node you are looking for from whatever variable value or address you need.  No real way around this other than exposing the name of the attribute node and checking it.

```
<xsl:sort select="@*[name(.)=/*/sortby]"/>
```

Comment: The Sum construct didn't work for me. I had to change it to sum(//FS_spcInvoice/@Gross_spcAmount) to make it work but I read that this can lead to bad performances. Any other ideas?

Comment: finally this worked for me um(/PropertySet/SiebelMessage/*/FS_spcInvoice/@Gross_spcAmount) moving on to the sort piece

Comment: Yes, I missed one level of depth in my suggestion, and yes, `//` can be a hit on performance.  I only used `*` so as not to have to type `ListOfXRX_spcUSCO_spcCOL_spcInvoice_spcAR_spcSummary` in my stylesheet.  For maintainability, you might want to put in the extra effort to include the complete element name.